# AES Decryption not working sometimes (Padding is Invalid and cannot be removed)

Tags: c#, .net, encryption, aes

Need help with this problem regaring encryption / decryption stuff.

I need to encrypt a GUID string and saved it to DB, which then will be decrypted and be used to identify a data.

However, sometimes the encrypted string is able to be decrypted and sometimes don't. it looks like there's something missing in my code:

```
public string Encrypt(string stringToEncrypt, string sEncryptionKey)
        {
            byte[] key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sEncryptionKey.PadLeft(32));
            byte[] inputByteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stringToEncrypt);
            byte[] encrypted;

            using (Aes aes = Aes.Create())
            {
                ICryptoTransform encryptor = aes.CreateEncryptor(key, IV);

                using MemoryStream msEncrypt = new();
                using CryptoStream csEncrypt = new(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write);
                csEncrypt.Write(inputByteArray, 0, inputByteArray.Length);
                csEncrypt.FlushFinalBlock();
                encrypted = msEncrypt.ToArray();
            }

            return HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Convert.ToBase64String(encrypted));
        }

public string Decrypt(string stringToDecrypt, string sEncryptionKey)
        {
            string result = string.Empty;

            byte[] key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sEncryptionKey.PadLeft(32));
            byte[] inputByteArray = Convert.FromBase64String(HttpUtility.UrlDecode(stringToDecrypt));
            Encoding encoding = Encoding.UTF8;

            using (Aes aes = Aes.Create())
            {
                ICryptoTransform decryptor = aes.CreateDecryptor(key, IV);

                using MemoryStream msDecrypt = new();
                using CryptoStream csDecrypt = new(msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write);
                csDecrypt.Write(inputByteArray, 0, inputByteArray.Length);
                csDecrypt.FlushFinalBlock();
                result = encoding.GetString(msDecrypt.ToArray());
            }

            return result;

        }
```

Both function uses the same IV and encryptionKey, and i've tested my code using these encrypted string

1. O900I6c8rXR1s9BrZCSzQxLdu7qLlGwxBNqtDMoMGLKsjDebDC69SgPimW1uMgNj <- not working
2. YLK5RiCvnKyKxKX3vybSIRxlyccut62Qdg4X%2bPPBwmU6fr%2fKBILsKoY3LGdtHN%2b1 <- working
3. %2bqX0P5NEg8KxK1h6OTCsDSid0CZv6idKtnrn4FHjK7NvvcCb7LJHsiRtzBlrA79k <- working

Somehow only the first one doesn't work despite using the same encryption function. The exception happend on the FlushFinalBlock() line on Decryption Method.

Encryption is done in .NET 6 app

Decryption is done in .NET 4.6.1 app

Here is sample key and IV to test:

> key = d4n40nly

> IV = new byte[] { 0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, >! 0x08, 0x09, 0x0A, 0x0B, 0x0C, 0x0D, 0x0E, 0x0F };

Can someone enlighten me on this?

Comment: Post complete (non-productive) sample data so that a repro is possible. Your data is missing key and plaintext. Also add the .NET version used.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - that does appear to be what the decode method is doing, on the line where `inputByteArray` is initialised. I would like to see this code de-stringified but the transformations do seem to be being reversed correctly.

Comment: How often does the problem occur? I cannot reproduce it even with 10000 calls ( using .NET 7).

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I noticed that now. I got confused by the noise, like URL-encoding (why???) and padding the password which *weakens* security. No need for UTF8 at all too - a GUID is a binary value already. I suspect the problems are caused by URL-encoding and the quirks of the various URL encoding methods in specific (older) runtimes

Comment: Please post that actually reproduces the problem, specifying the runtime *and* version you used. The various URL-encoding methods behave slightly differently, especially in old (and now discontinued) runtimes like .NET Framework 3.5 or .NET Framework 4..0. In any case, it would be a *lot* more secure to use the database's encryption functionality instead of rolling your own. That `Pad32` *weakens* security by severely reducing the number of possible passwords to just 32-character strings. The password isn't salted either, which means it can be cracked using brute force

Comment: Sorry forgot some details i posted

Encryption is done in .NET 6, however the Decryption is done in a .NET 4.6.1 but there's no problem when build using the same code

as for why i'm using url encoding is that the encrypted string will be used as a param for a url, is it unnecessary?

Comment: @Topaco

sample key i used is "d4n40nly", but as for the plain text i just used GUID.NewGuid().ToString()

sample code:
Encryptor ed = new();
string result = ed.Encrypt(Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "d4n40nly")

Comment: Please also post the IV.

Comment: byte[] IV = new byte[] { 0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08, 0x09, 0x0A, 0x0B, 0x0C, 0x0D, 0x0E, 0x0F };

Comment: A decryption without padding shows a plaintext that is corrupted over its entire length (not just a corrupted padding). This rather indicates that a different key was used during encryption. Are you sure that the problematic GUID was encrypted with the key used for decryption?

Comment: See here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/buDzuU

Comment: You will not be able to decrypt the cipher to get the plaintext, because O900I6c8rXR1s9BrZCSzQxLdu7qLlGwxBNqtDMoMGLKsjDebDC69SgPimW1uMgNj is an invalid cipher.

Comment: I tried with a different compiler here, the result is the same. Your cipher is an invalid. https://dotnetfiddle.net/vqwmSp

Comment: after some checking it looks like the http utility function causes the problem, since when unit testing it is fine, but after the encrypted string is taken from DB it cannot be decrypted.

anyway thanks for the response